# How to implment touch funcationality on a PC running Windows using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, touchscreen

I have implemented the touch functionality to my website using these code and it works fine for iPad/iPhone.

```
// registering touch events
function initTouchEvents() {

    // if a device is a touch device
    if (window.Touch) {
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
    }
}

// making items sortable in touch screen devices
function touchHandler(event) {

    var touches = event.changedTouches,
                    first = touches[0],
                    type = "";

    switch (event.type) {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove": type = "mousemove"; break;
        case "touchend": type = "mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }
    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, first.screenX, first.screenY,
                                  first.clientX, first.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);

    if (event.type == "touchmove") {

        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

But when I tested my website on touch screen PC, it doesn't run and I found out that the `window.Touch` only run for iPhone/iPad. And I also tried various other events like `typeof(window.ontouchstart != 'undefined')` and `('ontouchstart' in window || typeof TouchEvent != "undefined")` but it doesn't detect that it's touch screen and doesn't register the event for touch movement.

What I am asking here is for an event in javascript that can detect all the touch devices (that IOS/Android/Windows/OSX) and run register the events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phantom Limb makes desktop browsers simulate touch events

https://github.com/brian-c/phantom-limb

Answer (score 1):

i think chrome has "emulate touch events" in the console settings. try to check that out.

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> or just do <kbd>F12</kbd>, then click the gear icon in the lower right. then check "emulate touch events". i think that should trigger touch events.

Comment: but as I said it's a website and I want to run on all the browser, can't only implement in Chrome

Comment: but you can at least test touch events in chrome. also, you can bind handlers of the same function to both click and touch.

Comment: What version of Chrome would do that? Cannot find it in v18.

Comment: I use Chrome 19. A [similar answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150177/575527)

Comment: @Joseph yup I saw the option of emulating touch events, it's an option to test touch events on normal screen, thanks

Comment: @m90 if you didn't found the option, download Google Chrome Canary (http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs), an advanced tool for web developers