# Changing touchevents to click events dynamically

Tags: javascript, touch

I am working on a mobile app and have got lots of touch events on various elements. Unfortunately I cannot test my app on my pc browser as it does not support touchevents. Is there any way I can change all touch events to click events dynamically if I am running on a pc ( ofcourse by checking the useragent ) ?

Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate touch events in the chrome web developer tools:

[image]

Comment: Using the Chrome Developer Tools. Press F12 to launch it in Chrome.

Comment: ok found it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919191/simulating-touch-events-on-a-pc-browser

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Developer Tools support touch emulation. But it's not that comfort to use. So I just made a chrome extension for touch event emulation. It translate mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events to touchstart, touchmove, touchend. It actually simulate iphone5, so user agent also changed.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/touchphone-simulator/jijkpkhmnpbecppjhicgegndbbgfnngf