# jquery click event for tablets and touch screen phones

Tags: jquery, click, tablet, smartphone

Ok, I am fairly new to web development for mobile/tablet platforms. I am pretty confident though in developing for a browser environment.

My problem is that **I don't own any tablet (I am poor so have to fly blind) so it's hard for me to do testing**. I'm also quite anxious about the click events not working properly.

> How can I ensure that click and mousedown jquery events work on
>   tablets/smartphones correctly?

Is there any consensus on best practice for click events and tablets/smartphones?

Note: I am not developing a mobile only site - the site transforms shape for mobile.

Comment: Your could use this: `$(element).on('touchstart click', function(){...});`.

Comment: Emulators of help? http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/6-free-mobile-device-emulators-for-testing-your-site/

Comment: @Joe  i have same problem onclick not working on tablet , if use .on and print something then it works.alert i tried replcing with cosole.log but that onclick not working with that

Comment: I needed to upgrade to jQuery 1.7 to get Joe's code to work. After that it worked on my phone even without `touchstart`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mobile browsers will still respond to click events, though they will introduce a delay (usually around 300 ms). If you want a more responsive experience, you can try to detect if you are on a mobile platform and use either `touchstart` or `touchend` events. I find `touchend` is usually a better experience, mainly because the user's hand is still in the way when `touchstart` fires.

Something like this:

`$(element).on(isMobile ? 'touchend' : 'click', function(e) {...});`

Or you can use [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/), which will work for both desktop and mobile.

As for testing, you can read through the answers to this Stackoverflow question: [Simulating touch events on a PC browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919191/simulating-touch-events-on-a-pc-browser).