# Activate touch events on Chrome 71+

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, touch

I want to activate touch events on Chrome to facilitate the debugging of an app that uses `touchstart` and `touchend` events.

It seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919191/simulating-touch-events-on-a-pc-browser) is a bit outdated because I cannot get the `Overrides` menu when I go to the developer settings, not on Chrome nor on Chrome Developer. This is what I get on Chrome Dev 73:

[image: settings]

I've searched thoroughly in the settings but no sight of this checkbox. I've seen no up-to-date tutorial to activate them. How can I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two methods in the devtools:

1. Press Escape to show the drawer at the bottom. Choose menu > Sensors. At the bottom, set Touch = Force enabled.
2. Turn on Device Toolbar (second button at the top). Choose menu > Add device type. Set it to either "Mobile" or "Desktop (touch)".

Both of these should enable touch events.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/43EvDVGan6E

Comment: Neither of these currently work in Chrome for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a chrome flag. Type this address into the chrome URL bar:

```
chrome://flags/#touch-events
```

it should highlight the Touch Events API, after that just press the drop-down box and change it to enabled.[image]

Comment: This will enable detection by code like `"ontouchstart" in window`, not emulating the actual events with the mouse.